# Java Abstract class - does each class get copy of variable

Tags: java, abstract-class

```
public abstract class ExternalScript extends Script {

    String source;

    public abstract void setSource(String file);

    public abstract String getSource();
}
```

Lets say i have 3 classes that  extend from this abstract class.  My question is if in the abstract class itself i change the value of source will the other 3 child classes see this change ?  Or do they each get there own copy ? A friend of mine was discussing this with me during dinner and we want the truth.

Comment: What happened when you tried a program that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make that source variable protected so children can see it.

Each instance of the children of your class will have their own parent data.  Changing one will not affect any other in this case because String is immutable.

However, if the parent reference was mutable, and you initialized each of the children with the same reference, then all three would see their private parent value change.

If the class in question is mutable, you need to make defensive copies for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not static.  Each instance you create gets its own copy of the value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solitary instance of your class `ExternalScript` so your subclasses don't share any common memory but the contents of `ExternalScript` are rather "merged" into the subclasses, so no, changing the contents of one subclasses instance does not change the contents of another.